# how to get specific row values from table using mysql query without where condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table (crane_tbl)

```
cf_did  cf_firstname cf_comment   cf_cranetype 

1       Alexy         tfhgfnjh       2,3    
2       Thomas        fdghfgh       11,6,3  
3       Thomas         cgjkjhl      5,6,11,3        
4       Thomasxc       cgjkjhl      1,6,9,4         
5       Thomaseg       fdghgh       11,12,3     
6       Thomasm        fsgdfgbd     11,6,3  
7       Thomabs        dgtrty       7,9,11  
8       Rdgfghfdg      bfdhh        1,3,4   
9       Gngfdytyt      eertret      1,6,3   
10      Dvbgfj         hfdhhyrtyr   6,3
```

how to get 5th row values from this table using mysql query without where condition and don't specify any table field name??

Comment: Using ORDER BY (to ensure that your'e checking the entries in the ame order as you show here) and LIMIT (to specify which entry you want and how many you want)

Comment: What's the `case` between?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Whats wrong with a where clause?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY column_number LIMIT 4,1
```

but think about situation, when you table will change.

Comment: Maybe some `ORDER BY` should be added?

Comment: this code SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 4,1 is working ...but how to use  ORDER BY in this code ?

Answer (score 1):

Tables do not have a *fifth* row, because they represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering.

In this case, I presume you mean by the first column.  Then you can get the fifth -- based on this column -- by using `limit` and `offset`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by cf_did
limit 1 offset 4;
```

This can also be written as `limit 4, 1`.

`offset` starts counting at 0 for the first row, so it really means the number of rows to skip.

Also, if you have an index on `cf_did` (which is true if it is declared as the primary key), MySQL does not actually do a sort.